# How to do High End video encoding on BeagleboneBlak

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-encoding, beagleboneblack

As we know BeagleBone Black dont have a DSP on SoC specific for the Video processing but is there any way we can achieve that by adding some extra DSP board.

I mean like Raspberry got Video Processing, so anyone tried to integrate both to get, so we have both the things to make that work.

I know its not the optimal way and these both are different but i have only one BBB and one Raspberry and I am trying to achieve some 1080p video streaming with better quality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no DSP on BeagleBoneBlack, you need to use DSP functions. 
If your input is audio, you can use ALSA.

Comment: I dont think just DSP functions will be enough and can give the same output as for DSP and my input is HD 1080p video, so that's why i was thinking if its feasible to use the DSP available on another board to compensate that.

Comment: If you want an board to compensate BeagleBoneBlack, I recommend you BeagleBoard. It has DSP and easy to interface with BeagleBoneBlack.

Comment: Thanks and yeah i know that. I have the last option to buy Beagle Bone XM and integrate that but I was thinking if the already available raspberry can be of any use, that will be best and cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "dont have a DSP on SoC specific for the Video processing" - I think you mean what is usually called a VPU (Video Processing Unit), and indeed Beaglebone Black's AM3358 processor doesn't have it (source: http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/am3358)

x264 has ARM NEON optimizations, so it can encode video reasonably well  in software, 640x480@30fps should be fine, but 1920x1080@30fps is likely out of reach (you may get 8-10fps).

On Raspberry Pi, you can use gstreamer with omxh264enc to take advantage of the onboard VPU to encode video. I think it is a bit rough (not as solid as raspivid etc) but this should get you started: https://blankstechblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/hardware-video-encoding-progess-with-the-raspberry-pi/